What is the Latin translation of ‘The past is a thought’?
I tried Google translate and got

praeteritum est cogitatio

A friend who studied Latin 30 years ago said correct to the above or

praeteritum memoria est

However, he wasn’t sure if memoria should have a different ending.
What is the Latin translation of 'The past is a thought'?

Can you explain what you mean by "the past is a thought"? Just going into the meaning, maybe providing some context for it, will yield you better answers.

The past, as a concept, a thing we perceive is merely a thought in our minds in the present.
